# How to disable Emmet entirely for a specific syntax in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, emmet, package-control

I have the [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) package installed for Sublime Text 3 via Package Control. I do a lot of Markdown editing in Sublime, and I've noticed that as Markdown files get larger, inserting a tab by pressing my keyboard's `Tab` button gets slower and slower. However, when I disable Emmet, inserting tabs is snappy and quick again. This leads me to believe that Emmet trying to parse what I'm writing and searching for ways to expand it is slowing tabbing down significantly.

Things I have tried:

- `"ignored_packages": ["Emmet"]` in my syntax-specific user settings.
- `"tab_completion": false` in my global Sublime settings.
- `"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "text.html.markdown"` in my Emmet settings.

To be clear: I still want Emmet to run for other syntax/filetypes. I just want Emmet, or at least whatever part of Emmet's behaviour is slowing down my tabbing, to be disabled when I'm writing in Markdown (`*.md`) files, or whichever files have the markdown syntax selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try new Emmet 2 extension (still in development): https://github.com/emmetio/sublime-text-plugin

It should work much faster and better

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you :).